# Unable to install a package via pip

Tags: pip, simple-salesforce

I am trying to install simple-salesforce==0.72.2 via pip and get this error on CentOS 7.

```
 pip install simple-salesforce==0.72.2
Collecting simple-salesforce==0.72.2
  Downloading simple_salesforce-0.72.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests[security] in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=0.13 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ndg-httpsclient in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=0.7 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL>=0.13->requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL>=0.13->requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL>=0.13->requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL>=0.13->requests[security]->simple-salesforce==0.72.2)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "/home/points2shop/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 156, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/email/feedparser.py", line 99, in push
    data, self._partial = self._partial + data, ''
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

What could be wrong? The same command worked on other machines with same configuration.

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried the following command ? `pip install -U simple-salesforce==0.72.2` maybe you have other dependencies that needs to be updated or something

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein, I don't want to use -U blindly. That could break the apps that depend on particular versions of packages.

Comment: So in this case it would be better if you used something like [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) in order to manage multiple version of python and its packages without worrying about breaking other apps

Comment: Why do you assume I am not using virtualenv?

Comment: because if you are using virtualenv you should be able to create a separate environment for each python project in this case you don't have to worry about breaking anything

Comment: Solution?  I'm getting the same Traceback on Windows and going in circles just trying to get ldap re-installed after a disk imaging error.  I've even re-installed Python with no luck.

Comment: My problem was permission on the virtualenv directory. Accidentally, the user did not have write permissions. Fixing the permissions solved my problem.